# Getting Document Object Model of a tag from HTML code in java

Tags: javascript, java, syntax-error

Does anybody know how can get Document Object Model (DOM) of a tag like button from html Code? This is what i've got so far...

```
JEditorPane p = new JEditorPane();
p.setContentType("text/html");
p.setText(" <!DOCTYPE html>\\n\n" +
"    <html dir=\"ltr\" lang=\"en\">\\n\n" +
"    <head>\\n\n" +
"    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; \" />\\n\n" +
"    <title>Alidoosti</title>\\n\n" +
"    </head>\\n\n" +
"    <body>\\n\n" +
"    <button id=\"miti\" type=\"submit\">Search</button>\n" +
"    </body>\\n\n" +
"    </html>\\n"); // Document text is provided below.
HTMLDocument d = (HTMLDocument) p.getDocument();


ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
try {

engine.eval("function getDomPath(el) {\n" +
"  var stack = [];\n" +
"  while ( el.parentNode != null ) {\n" +
"    console.log(el.nodeName);\n" +
"    var sibCount = 0;\n" +
"    var sibIndex = 0;\n" +
"    for ( var i = 0; i < el.parentNode.childNodes.length; i++ ) {\n" +
"      var sib = el.parentNode.childNodes[i];\n" +
"      if ( sib.nodeName == el.nodeName ) {\n" +
"        if ( sib === el ) {\n" +
"          sibIndex = sibCount;\n" +
"        }\n" +
"        sibCount++;\n" +
"      }\n" +
"    }\n" +
"    if ( el.hasAttribute('id') && el.id != '' ) {\n" +
"      stack.unshift(el.nodeName.toLowerCase() + '#' + el.id);\n" +
"    } else if ( sibCount > 1 ) {\n" +
"      stack.unshift(el.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ':eq(' + sibIndex + ')');\n" +
"    } else {\n" +
"      stack.unshift(el.nodeName.toLowerCase());\n" +
"    }\n" +
"    el = el.parentNode;\n" +
"  }\n" +
"  return stack.slice(1); // removes the html element\n" +
"}"+
"var path = getDomPath("+d+".getElementById('miti'));\n" +
"console.log(path.join(' > '));");
```

But I got this Error:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:26:60 Missing space after numeric literal
}var path = getDomPath(javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument@75f32542.getElementById('miti'));
                                                            ^ in <eval> at line number 26 at column number 60
```

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jsoup for this. Add it to your classpath and use it like this

```
String html = "[YOUR HTML IN HERE]"
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements buttons = doc.select("button");
```

Afterwhich for each Element retrieved from the select("button") call you can get the parent stack by using the [parents()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#parents--) method

Read up on Jsoup here: https://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `d` is of type HTMLDocument, which, when concatenated with a string, invokes the java's method `toString()` which (for the current type you are using) returns a string like `javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument@75f32542`.

I guess you would prefer to use the javascript object `document`.

May I ask what you are trying to do? This seems an incredibly complicated way to do not much more than parsing some x(ht)ml....

Comment: thanks for your reply, in fact I want to extract DoM path ( Document Object Model path)  of all of  buttons in html code in java. Do you have any better solution?

Comment: yes. either parse it using a DOM parser (will produce https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html), with some xpath you can get all buttons, and recursively looking for their parents you will find the absolute path. Or, if the html is not xml-well formed, you can use a lib like Jericho which is syntax-tolerant.